# How to tell if item was selected or menu dismissed from comboBoxWillDismiss in NSComboBox?

Tags: cocoa, drop-down-menu

I have a dialog where changing the value in an NSComboBox triggers changes to other parts of the dialog. We apply the changes in controlTextDidEndEditing and comboBoxWillDismiss, but it turns out that if the user used the keyboard to select an item but then presses escape to cancel the selection, indexOfSelectedItem returns that item, even though the text doesn't get updated to that selection. How can we tell whether the user selected an item or dismissed the menu without selecting an item?

Comment: Have you tried the action method instead of `controlTextDidEndEditing` and `comboBoxWillDismiss`?

Comment: @Willeke: the action only triggers when pressing enter inside the textbox (not in the menu, nor when clicking in the menu)

Comment: The action should be triggered when the user selects a menu item.

Comment: @Willeke thanks, I see that that works in a test app. Now to figure out why it's not working in my real app. If you make an answer I'll accept it.